# Exception throw out when trying to open the camera using Xam.Plugin.Media

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I'm trying to open the camera using `await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotAsync()` Im getting below exception. It doesn't open any camera in the application.

> Field overflow on store `InterpretedSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineVT.<>7__wrap2`

My code as below,

```
        public UserProfilePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            CameraButton.Clicked += CameraButton_Clicked;
            BindingContext = new UserProfileViewModel(this.Navigation);
        }  

        private async void CameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
               
                // Supply media options for saving our photo after it's taken.
                var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Receipts",
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg"
                };

                // Take a photo of the business receipt.
                try
                {
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);

                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Xaml page like below,

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" />
        <Button x:Name="CameraButton" Text="Take Photo" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

How to get my camera open and take a photo in xamarin. Below are the confugarations,

> Xam.Plugin.Media = v3.1.2
>
> Xamarin.Forms = v2.5.0.121934
>
> VS2017

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar problem with Xamarin ad authentication: Field overflow on store `InterpretedSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineVT.extraQueryParameters`.

Comment: Are you trying with Xamarin Live player? or actual physical device?

Comment: Was trying with Xamarin Live Player. Switched to physical device and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you're trying to run Audio, Camera kind of features in the **Xamarin Live Player**.

Plugging actual physical device for debugging or release will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be in the target file name of the photo:

```
Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg"
```

The date contains characters that are invalid in a file path and that causes the exception.

You can use an alternative format that is suitable for file names:

```
Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")}.jpg"
```

Comment: I have changed as your suggestion. But no luck.